# Ignore persistence unit definitions that have PersistenceUnitTransactionType = RESOURCE_LOCAL

Tags: jpa, wildfly

I have a `Wildfly 8` container and an EAR with a `persistence.xml` inside. There are multiple persistence units defined.

Is there a way to ignore the process of the persistence unit definitions that have `PersistenceUnitTransactionType = RESOURCE_LOCAL` at the deployment of the `EAR`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to tell wildfly to ignore specific peristence-unit in peristence.xml by adding property

```
<properties>
   <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false" />
</properties>
```

So wildfly will not ignore all peristence-units with `PersistenceUnitTransactionType=RESOURCE_LOCAL` but all with the property set.

Comment: This stilll works in Wildfly 23.0.0.Final.